# How to print the comment author profile link

Tags: wordpress, comments

I want to show comment author profile link inside the loop of my WordPress website.

I've tried `get_comment_author_url()` but it shows Facebook profile link of the comment author, instead I want to print his profile link in my WordPress website.

The final result should be something like `example.com/author/john-smith`

I cannot print only the nickname because `John Smith` (in camel case with space) is the nickname and displayed name and it should be formatted (users might be named with accents or special characters).

Answer (score 0):

function force_comment_author_url($comment)
{
    // does the comment have a valid author URL?
    $no_url = !$comment->comment_author_url || $comment->comment_author_url == 'http://';

```
if ($comment->user_id && $no_url) {
    // comment was written by a registered user but with no author URL
    $comment->comment_author_url = 'http://www.example.com/?author=' . $comment->user_id;
}
return $comment;
```

}
add_filter('get_comment', 'force_comment_author_url');